# How to ignore keyboard input buffer in between two `read`

Tags: shell-script, scripting, keyboard

When I run a script like

```
read -n 1 -p 'Enter first variable: ' var1
if echo "${var1}" | grep -iq "^y"
then
    echo "okay"
else
    echo "not okay"
fi

sleep 2

read -n 1 -p 'Enter second variable: ' var2
if echo "${var2}" | grep -iq "^y"
then
    echo "okay"
else
    echo "not okay"
fi
```

If I run this code, hit <kbd>y</kbd> and then hit <kbd>n</kbd> in span of 2 seconds, the <kbd>n</kbd> is saved in buffer and given to the next `read` which is why it doesn't wait and ask for user input for `Enter second variable:`, it simply gives the key in buffer i.e <kbd>n</kbd> here.

**For making myself clear, I am paraphrasing my question in different words in the following questions but the question is just one.**

How do I stop keys being buffered to the memory ? **OR**

How do I ignore the user input in the buffer for second variable `var2` ? **OR**

How do I disable/ignore keyboard input in between my first and second `read` so that whatever I type in the span of 2 seconds after the first `read`, it does not go as an input to the second `read`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to call the `tcflush()` POSIX function, to flush the pending input.

For instance with:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'tcflush 0,0'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `bash` shell, then in a simple way you can try to read a single character from the input using a timeout of almost 0. This returns true if anything was read, so you need to try again. For example, put this function at the start of your script and call it between the sleep and the following read:

```
flush(){
  while read -N 1 -t 0.01
  do :
  done
}
```

Comment: Thank you meuh, I understand you answered first and this sure solved my problem but I'm marking Stephane's answer as accepted because the answer he gave was asked in the question. To just ignore everything user has typed. Thanks for helping meuh.